# Use <span> on paragraph with createTextNode

Tags: javascript, html

I want color one word on a paragraph but I create this paragraph with TextNode then  is display like some text.

Example :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to create a Text Node.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var t = document.createTextNode("Hello World <span style=\"color: #BA0000\">error</span> ");
  document.body.appendChild(t);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to create an **element** not text. The **textNode** is going to display whatever text you give it instead of build out the html you pass it. So you'll want to create the elements inidivually in variables or set the innerHTML of a parent element with whatever content you have like the `<span>`.

Try creating an element like a paragraph tag then setting it's innerhtml like below:

```js
 var t = document.createElement('p');
 t.innerHTML = "Hello World <span style=\"color:#BA0000\">error</span> ";
```

This will give you the element with the html in it like you want, isntead of just text. See the example below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to create a Text Node.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var t = document.createElement('p');
  t.innerHTML = "Hello World <span style=\"color:#BA0000\">error</span> ";
  document.body.appendChild(t);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an element. Using `createTextNode` just creates text.

Here's how you can achieve this using `createElement`

```
function myFunction() {
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.style.color = "#BA0000";
  span.innerText = "error";
  document.body.appendChild(span);
}
```

---

So your complete code will look something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to make a BUTTON element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var t = document.createTextNode("Hello World ");
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.style.color = "#BA0000";
  span.innerText = "error";
  document.body.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(span);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create a text node, it doesn't parse the HTML that is being printed. You may want to change the code slightly to be something like the following which creates HTML elements:

```
var t = document.createElement('p');
t.innerText = "Hello World ";

var s = document.createElement('span');
s.style.color = "#BA0000";
s.innerText = "Error";
t.appendChild(s);

document.body.appendChild(t);
```

This will create your expected result.

Answer (score 1):

you should create a span element and appending it to the body.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to create a Text Node.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
const span = document.createElement('span');
span.textContent = 'error'
span.style.cssText = 'color: #BA0000';

  var t = document.createTextNode("Hello World ");
    document.body.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(span);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

createTextNode() is [used to escape HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode). Try changing the color by [targeting the element by an ID](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_color.asp). Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/mmj/pen/wvaBaLK)

```
<p>Click the button to create a Text Node<span id='color_me'>color me</span></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("color_me").style.color = "#ff0000";
}
</script>
```